# Char * w/ Memory Leak

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an issue identifying what is causing the memory leak in my program. Below is the code that I am running:

```
char *input[999];
//exec commands
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++)
{
    string current = "";
    string word = "";
    int k = 0;
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < commands.at(i).size(); j++) //iterate through letters
    {
        current = commands.at(i);
        //cout << "current: " << current << endl;
        if(current[j] == ' ')
        {
            input[k] = new char[word.size() + 1];
            strcpy(input[k], word.c_str());
            k++;
            word = "";
        }
        else
            word += current[j]; //add letter
        //cout << "word: " << word << endl;
    }
    input[k] = new char[word.size() + 1];
    strcpy(input[k], word.c_str());
    k++;

    input[k] = NULL;

    //...
    //...

    for(int z = 0; z <= k; z++)
    {
        delete[] input[z];
    }
}
```

Running this code through valgrind, I see that I have memory that is definitely lost. To attempt to recreate the scenario and debug, I have a smaller scale version of the above code here:

```
int main()
{
    char* var[999];
    string s = "1234";

    var[0] = new char[4 + 1];
    strcpy(var[0], s.c_str());

    delete [] var[0];
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not have any memory leaks according to valgrind. What am I not de-allocating in my original code? What is my test code doing that my original code is not doing? Thank you, I appreciate any help.

Comment: `commands` is a vector that holds separate bash commands (stored as strings).  It would hold `ls && pwd` where `ls`, `&&`, and `pwd` are separate indices in `commands`.

Comment: Not directly related but I guess you wanted to express `z < k` instead of `z <= k` in your delete loop :)

Comment: Wouldn't I want to iterate all the way to the end at `k`? The last thing I do at index `k` is `input[k] = NULL`.  Does it not make a difference doing a `delete` on it?

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you do this anyway... Since you always delete these items first, you more or less ensure it doesn't point to anything...

Comment: Please, just use a vector and avoid all the new/delete headaches.  This is a very C like solution for C++ code.

Comment: I wish I could Michael but I am intentionally doing this because I pass this `char*` to `execvp` that takes in `const char *file` and `char *const argv[]` as arguments. So I do `execvp(input[0], input)`

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Any chance you've accidentally reused or reset `k` somewhere inside the `//...` code that isn't shown?

Comment: If all you want to do is pass a char * to execvp(), just use const_cast<>.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeshare.io/JcgL7) is my full code if you want to see it for yourself.  I don't know how to simplify and reproduce the same error (hence my second code example).  The code snippet I provided here starts at line 393. As far as I know, the `char*` is the only thing that allocates memory in my code.
@TheUndeadFish i do not reset `k` anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You usually need to declare your char*'s with a new if you are going to use delete[] on it later in the code. Looks like just a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in c++ but you should declare input as follows

```
char **input=new char*[999];
```

Comment: Is this the proper way to do it or is this just a matter of style?

If I do this, my definitely lost memory increases significantly.

Also, the same amount of memory that leaked before changing this line of code switched from definitely lost memory to indirectly lost memory.

Comment: this is the proper way, you are allocating memory dinamically, actually you can do this:
`char **input=new char*[commands.size()];` maybe 999 is not enougth big

Comment: however command.size() could not be big enought since you're increasing k inside de second for (if a space is found) so the question is how big is command.size()?

Comment: the question is why do you delete input at the end, do you use only the last word in every kth iteration? `delete[] input[z]`